# AutoCompleteTextView Adapter causing resource compilation error

Tags: arrays, autocompletetextview

I am trying to give an AutoCompleteTextView all the countries (in french) as suggestions,
i inserted all the countries names as items in string-array in `strings.xml` :

```
<string-array name="countries_array">
        <item>Afghanistan</item>
        <item>Albanie</item>
        <item>Algérie</item>
        <item>Samoa américaines</item>
        <item>Andorre</item>
        ...
```

My layout file code :

```
<RelativeLayout>
...
 <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/lieuAct"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/secActivite"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="Pays du Lieu d'activité"
        android:padding="10dp"
 />
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java code :

```
 lieuAct =  (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.lieuAct);
        descriptionEntreprise = findViewById(R.id.description);

        String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(Step2RECaccount.this, R.layout.step_2_rec_account, countries);
        lieuAct.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Tried to change gradle compile sdk and other things but nothing seems to work
tried having the string-array in separate file inside values folder but same thing it doesn't work
also tried to change from AutoCompleteTextView to EditText but obviously setAdapter doesn't work for edit texts
what should i change ?